# mysql container connection refused

Tags: mysql, symfony, docker

i have a docker-compose with a mysql service, it work fine when i establish the connection with mysql workbench, but when i trying to connect with my symfony app, it throw me an connection refused error.

The host, port, user and password are correctly setted.

this is my compose:

```
version: "3.1"

services:

  mysql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/mysql/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .data:/usr/data
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=000000
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=000000
    ports:
      - "3200:3306"

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm

  php-fpm:
    build: docker/php-fpm
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./docker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

this is the dockerfile for mysql:

```
FROM mysql:5.7


ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
ENV MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

COPY ./docker/mysql/my_database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

EXPOSE 3306
```

this are my symfony config params:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: mysql
    database_port: 3200
    database_name: my_database
    database_user: admin
    database_password: '000000'
```

and this is the error throwed:

```
"exception": {
        "message": "An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused",
        "code": 0,
        "previous": {
            "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused",
            "code": 2002,
            "previous": {
                "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused",
                "code": 2002,
                "trace": [
                    {
                        "namespace": "",
                        "short_class": "",
                        "class": "",
                        "type": "",
                        "function": "",
                        "file": "/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php",
                        "line": 43,
                        "args": []
                    },
                    {
                        "namespace": "",
                        "short_class": "PDO",
                        "class": "PDO",
                        "type": "->",
                        "function": "__construct",
                        "file": "/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php",
                        "line": 43,
                        "args": [
                            [
                                "string",
                                "mysql:host=mysql;port=3200;dbname=my_database;charset=UTF8;"
                            ],
                            [
                                "string",
                                "admin"
                            ],
                            [
                                "string",
                                "000000"
                            ],
                            [
                                "array",
                                []
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: You are connecting to port 3200 from Symphony while MySQL is configured to run on 3306. You also defined Docker to expose 3306 and not 3200.

Comment: hi, the port is mapped to 3200 by docker, i can connect to the database whit workbench using the port 3200

Comment: Yes, but you're mapping 3200 to 3306 from external to internal. Internally within Docker you exposed it as 3306. ;)

Comment: thank you man, you are absolutely right, I did not know, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you expose the port 3306 of your mysql container and map it to port 3200 this means that the outside world should access it using the port 3200. But other containers using the same network must use the port 3306.

Comment: wow, I did not know that, thank you very much, now it's working perfect.

Comment: I've logged in just to +1 your answer!!! It's solved my problem. I just didn't realize that, within the same network, what counts is the docker port and not the exposed port.